# ngClass and form validation timeline

Tags: angular

I want to display a red error message if the form is invalid. I accomplished it using ngClass but the red error message displays at page load even if the model is valid.

I have simple ngClass and a simple form:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'has-error': form.controls.roleName.valid == false}">
...
constructor(){
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
                roleName: ['', Validators.required]
            });

    this.getModel();
}
```

I load the form model in ctor so form.controls.roleName value is not empty on page load. But the div has class="has-error" in it, eg: `<div class="has-error">`. When user interacts with the page, which I assume makes the change detection to work, div becomes like this: `<div class>`.

I'm thinking that validation works before I bind the model. What should I do to not display error message after binding the form model on page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to be combined with `touched` or `pristine`

```
<div [ngClass]="{'has-error': form.controls.roleName.valid == false && form.controls.roleName.touched}">
```